# Google Drive SDK Push Notifications, receiving wrong changes id

Tags: push-notification, google-drive-api

When I subscribe to all changes of my Drive account, sometimes I receive changes with wrong id. According to my observations changes of specific file are aggregated in last change with some time period.

For example:
If I change file in my drive and if I have received 3 notifications with ids: "#21, #22, #23", I expected that I can get change of "#23", if there is no more changes to that file. But sometimes I receive last change with id greater than it exists. When I use API changes list, I get lastlargestChangeId = receivedChangesId - 1.

I have tested it with google examples and I get the same results:

[push notifications test](https://pushnotificationsplayground.appspot.com/all)

> {"notification_id": "xxxxxxxxxxx", "resource_state": "change", "expiration": "Mon, 07 Jul 2014 13:58:37 GMT", "self_link": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/changes/**3387**"}
>
> {
>    "kind": "drive#changeList",
>    "etag": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
>    "selfLink": ".../changes?startChangeId=3340",
>    **"largestChangeId": "3386"**,
>    "items": [
>     ...
>    ]
>   }

Am I wrong?

Comment: I'm running into this exact problem.  When I "remove" (not delete) a file in drive, I get a notification with a changeID.  Doing a "getChange( changeID ) returns a 404, but when I check the "getLargestChangeID", I find that the changeID that I was given by the notification is one digit larger than what the largest change ID really is.  Can someone explain this please?

Comment: Same here, looks like a bug... When I upload a new file, I receive a change notification, the provided id is incorrect. But the id - 1 is OK.

Comment: If it can help, on upload I also receive "change" for the x-goog-resource-state, and no "add" at all.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Google categorized it as a bug:
https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3706

Star it so Google can prioritize it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the official answer:

> After talking with our engineers, this actually is working as
>   intended. The change ID given in the push notification (the ID and the
>   self link that contains that same ID) remain valid only as long as
>   there are no newer changes on a particular resource. Take the
>   following example scenario on a user's drive with push notifications
>   being sent for all changes. 1) Resource A (a file or folder, etc)
>   changes. 2) Drive API sends a push notification with a change ID
>   (example 1234). 3) This change ID (and the selflink) can be used now
>   to successfully pull up the change. 4) Resource A changes again. 5)
>   Drive API sends a push notification with change ID 1235. Note that
>   change IDs are monotonically increasing. 6) Accessing the earlier
>   change ID (1234) through a changes.get or the self link will 404 now
>   because there is a newer change on the same resource. 7) You can still
>   access change ID 1235 here.
>
> In general, you should not expect to be able to get a particular
>   change ID with changes.get. Any resource is only in the changes stream
>   once. So as soon as the resource has a newer change, the old change ID
>   is invalid. Some commenters have noted that you can do changeID - 1 to
>   get this change. However, this will not always work. In my testing, I
>   have gotten a 404 on both the change ID and for change ID - 1.
>   Instead, you should sync a given set of resources and note the largest
>   change ID of that set. Then, when you get push notifications in the
>   future, see if the change ID you get in the push notification is newer
>   than the largest you stored. If so, use changes.list in order to get
>   all of the resource changes between the last change ID you have seen /
>   stored and the one you just received.
>
> tldr; Do not count on change IDs existing with changes.get. Use
>   changes.list instead to get all changes from a base change ID to the
>   change ID you get in the push notification.

https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3706

Comment: In my issue the problem is that when I receive changes notification sometimes it's value doesn't even exist. I can check that fact with the help of changes _LIST API_ and _GET API_ with **RECIEVED_ID - 1**. If it would be the last **change ID** I could get it with _GET_ request but I couldn't. 
In the example above in my problem at step 5 Drive API sends **1236 ID** instead of **1235** (real change ID).  And I can't get it with _GET_ request and _LIST_ request. But I can get (1236 -1) because it is received with _LIST_ and _GET_ requests.